# Why is it that repeated measures ANOVA does not allow continuous between-subjects factor?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, spss

I have a continuous DV measured in Time 1 and 2; time is my primary IV here.

Also, there's a continuous, time-invariant moderator for each participant.

I want to see whether the effect of Time on DV (DV difference between Time 1 and 2) is moderated by the continuous moderator.

In SPSS I could use GLM-repeated measures, put two DV into within-subjects variables box, and put the continuous moderator to the covariates box. That said, I don't think this is entirely appropriate, because the continuous variable was a moderator (an IV), not a covariate. Nevertheless, SPSS seems to by default estimate a full model even with covariates, so the test of within-subjects table gives the F test results for the interaction term.

I can also run a mixed model, with each subject having random intercept. The results are similar with the GLM-repeated measures but not identical.

My question is why GLM-repeated measures ANOVA does not allow continuous between-subjects factor, or more precisely, it treats it as a categorical variable. I have a hunch that it's due to how repeated measures ANOVA treat the random effects, but I'd love to know more about why in more detail.